# Spring security returns HTTP 403 after successful authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using spring 4.3.10.RELEASE and spring-security 4.2.3.RELEASE
When I try open /admin after successful authentication i get 403, but i have all required authorities, look at tomcat log.

My security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll().and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET")).and()
                .csrf().and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, enabled FROM app_user WHERE username = ?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, role FROM app_user_role WHERE username = ?");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
```

My Tomcat's log:

```
2017-07-28 14:18:15 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 - Checking match of request : '/admin'; against '/resources/**'
2017-07-28 14:18:15 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 - Checking match of request : '/admin'; against '/admin/**'
2017-07-28 14:18:15 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:219 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /admin; Attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')]
2017-07-28 14:18:15 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:348 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@f9ea146f: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ADMIN,USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 9F780DC552AED23804184D55F3F9BF0D; Granted Authorities: ADMIN, USER
2017-07-28 14:18:15 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:66 - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@6e6a7061, returned: -1
2017-07-28 14:18:15 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:185 - Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! The key is prefix "ROLE_"

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .rolePrefix("ROLE_")
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, enabled FROM app_user WHERE username = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, role FROM app_user_role WHERE username = ?");
}
```